# Why is Rails not recognizing newly installed version of Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have recently installed ruby 2.5.1 seemingly successfully, however when I type the command `ruby -v` into the "Command Prompt with ruby and rails" it returns the old value of 2.2.6.  The strange thing is that when i type `ruby -v` into the normal Command prompt it returns the newly installed version 2.5.1.

I feel that I must change the configuration of the Rails environment somehow.

when I open the "command prompt with ruby and rails" it shows the following configuration

```
git:
  user.name:  USER_NAME_HERE
  user.email: EMAIL@********.com
  version:    git version 1.9.4.msysgit.2

ruby:
  bin:        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/bin/ruby.exe
  version:    ruby 2.2.6p396 (2016-11-15 revision 56800) [i386-mingw32]

rails:
  bin:        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/bin/rails.bat
  version:    Rails 5.1.6
```

How do I get Rails to recognize the newly installed version of ruby?

Comment: Check your `Gemfile`. It probably has a ruby version hardcoded.

Comment: i tried hard coding the verion number in the gem file with "ruby '2.5.1'" and typing "bundle install":     C:\Sites\postgresapp>bundle install
Your Ruby version is 2.2.6, but your Gemfile specified 2.5.1. anyway the ruby environment i included above appears before loading any particular app. so i think it is not related to the gemfile or any particular project.

Answer (score 0):

RailsInstaller is hard coded to the version of Ruby it installs. 
You can see this is the lines Ruby: bin and version.
You probably installed Ruby 2.5 somewhere else. There are two approaches you can take

- Before anything! Backup the RailsInstaller and Sites folders!!!! REALLY!
- Adjust the RailsInstaller scripts to point to your new Ruby
- Overwrite the older Ruby with the newer one and adjust the scripts where paths are different.

The key file is C:\RailsInstaller\Rubyx.x.x\setup_environment.bat

I suspect the key line (near line 11) is

SET RUBY_DIR=%CD%

I *think* that if this is changed to the path of the Ruby you want to use, operation will shift to that version. Might also need to change

SET ROOT_DIR=%CD%

To point to the RailsInstaller main folder.

Comment: You may also need to rewire git as the version used by RailsInstaller no longer works.

Comment: yes i have been having a similar problem with git for a while since i updated but nothing happened in the same way. i have been getting round it by using the git GUI, but it is inconvenient. how to rewire git at the same time?

Comment: could you clarify the answer. should i only do ONE of those. how do i adjust the RailsInstaller scripts? (i dont know what a script is). how do i overwrite the old ruby? Should i type this --> "SET RUBY_DIR=%CD%" exactly? I am not an expert in rails so a few more pointers would be useful. thanks

Comment: Sorry, yes, only the backup plus one. The notes at the end refer to the moving pointers approach, not the overwrite approach.

Comment: No, that is a line in the setup batch file that you need to edit. If that is too difficult to figure out, maybe you should leave well enough alone and stick to the version of Ruby you have? Sorry, I cannot be more detailed in this venue.